# How to close WORD or EXCEL files opened by DSO FRAMER control?

Tags: c#, .net, dsoframer

I am using DSO-Framer control for opening WORD and EXCEL files. But DSO-Framer control is not closing the instances of this office files after preview. Please give me some solutions to close the instances which are opened by DSO-framer control.

Comment: What's a DSO-Framer control?

Comment: It was a component that was discontinued about 9 years ago.  Embedding support is rapidly disappearing from Office, there is no future.